# Change the default tab look of bootstrap 5.2

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

How do I change the look of tabs like this (need not be green colot, instead primary color of boostrap works for me)

[image]

instead of

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">



<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Active</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link disabled">Disabled</a>
  </li>
</ul></body>

</html>
```

Comment: Bootstrap offers you predefined CSS. If you want to custom, you'll need to do it in CSS, or eventualy TailwindCSS which is more specific than bootstrap

Comment: Well, create a CSS file, add classes to your tags in html and custom its style in your CSS file

Comment: Here is an example : https://codepen.io/bastoscunha/pen/JzJjZm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your CSS:

```css
a.nav-link.active {
  border: transparent;
  border-bottom: 4px solid green !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Active</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link disabled">Disabled</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```